# Docker Compose + Postgres + Nodejs + knex API ão conecta no banco

Tags: node.js, postgresql, docker, knex.js

Ola

Estou estudando Docker Compose, fiz uma API simples para fazer CRUD de usuário, porem quero subir um container para rodar o node e um com postgres e eles se comunicando fiz o seguinte 'docker compose.yml' :

```
version: "3.3"
services: 
  app:
    build: .
    depends_on: 
      - db
    command: yarn dev
    ports: 
      - "3333:3333"
    volumes: 
      - .:/user/app
    links: 
      - db

  db:
    image: postgres
    restart: always
    ports: 
      - "5433:5432"
    volumes: 
      - /var/lib/postgresql/data
    environment:
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: -senha-
      POSTGRES_USER: -user-
```

eu deixei a porta externa como a 5433 porque já tenho um outro banco postgres rodando na porta 5432

Meu arquivo 'knexfile.js' esta assim:

```
// Update with your config settings.

module.exports =  {

  development: {
    client: 'sqlite3',
    connection: {
      filename: './dev.sqlite3'
    }
  },

  staging: {
    client: 'postgresql',
    connection: {
      database: 'my_db',
      user:     'username',
      password: 'password'
    },
    pool: {
      min: 2,
      max: 10
    },
    migrations: {
      tableName: 'knex_migrations'
    }
  },

  production: {
    client: 'postgresql',
    connection: {
      port: 5433,
      database: 'nome banco',
      user:     'user',
      password: 'senha'
    },
    pool: {
      min: 2,
      max: 10
    },
    migrations: {
      tableName: 'knex_migrations'
    }
  }

};
```

quando executo o `docker-compose up` ele cria e executa muito bem se eu tento me comunicar com a API com Insomnia funciona, se tento me comunicar com o container postgres com Dbeaver funciona do mesmo jeito, porem a API não se comunica com o banco, o erro:

```
{
  "errno": -111,
  "code": "ECONNREFUSED",
  "syscall": "connect",
  "address": "127.0.0.1",
  "port": 5433
}
```

O que estou fazendo de errado para eles não se comunicarem?
Já procurei muito sobre e não encontrei nada.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uma vez que o erro mostra que você tentou usar a porta 5433, acredito que esteja usando a configuração `production` e tentando "ligar" um container diretamente ao outro. Neste caso, a porta que deve ser usada é a interna (5432) e não a "exposta" no host.
O mesmo vale para o servidor, que deverá ser "db" (o nome do seu container no docker compose). Como não está especificado, presumo que o driver assuma o valor 127.0.0.1 (conforme a mensagem de erro). Seria então necessário especificá-lo, caso contrário a sua aplicação tentará conectar à uma base de dados dentro do mesmo container.

Comment: Obrigado tdvias, pior que ontem eu tinha testado colocar o ip mesmo do container de banco, na teoria era pra dar certo mas eu estava usando ainda a porta 5433, só após ler sua resposta que me dei conta que a porta tinha que ser 5432 pois os container estavam dentro da rede do docker n do meu PC em si.

Answer (score 1):

Existem alguns problemas com o seu `knexfile.js`.

A lib padrão recomendada para utilizar com o knex é a lib [pg](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pg)

Então você teria que modificar em seu arquivo a linha client para ter o valor:

```
client: 'pg',
```

Esta lib que está tentando utilizar até existe porém eu não recomendo, visto que a ultima versão lançada é de 6 anos atrás e a lib está na versão 0.0.1.

Outro problema é que em seu arquivo `knexfile.js` está faltando a linha host, segundo a documentação do knex um adapter de conexão completo para postgres seria:

```
var knex = require('knex')({
  client: 'pg',
  version: '7.2',
  connection: {
    host : '127.0.0.1', //<--adicionar esta linha
    user : 'your_database_user',
    password : 'your_database_password',
    database : 'myapp_test',
    port: 5432
  }
});
```

Quando esta linha é omitida o knex utiliza o valor padrão que é `127.0.0.1`.

Só que o seu banco de dados está rodando em sua instância docker, então você deve modificar o host para:

```
host : 'db'
```

Que é o nome da sua instância do banco de dados no arquivo `docker-compose.yml`.

O knexfile.js final seria:

```
var knex = require('knex')({
  client: 'pg',
  version: '7.2',
  connection: {
    host : 'db', //<--adicionar esta linha
    user : 'your_database_user',
    password : 'your_database_password',
    database : 'myapp_test',
    port: 5432
  }
});
```

Verifique que troquei a lib do banco de dados então é necessário instalar a lib `pg`. Atualmente esta lib está na versão `8.3.0` (08/2020). Na documentação do knex ele recomenda a 7.2 (talvez eles usem essa versão (7.2) por causa de compatibilidade com o query builder do knex).

Comment: danizavtz muito obrigado pela resposta, esse era parte do problema, eu na verdade ja tinha instalado o ```pg``` porem não estava usando ele no knex pq achei que era o postgresql kkkk

Comment: e a outra parte foi o host: eu n fazia ideia q tinha q colocar o mesmo nome gerado no compose 
porem eu reparei numa coisa que o tdvias tmb respondeu abaixo a porta dentro do container tem que ser a 5432 porque a que eu setei 5433 é a porta pra acessar de fora da rede do docker